# How to find path between two points In android Map with time distance?

Tags: android, google-maps, direction

I am new bie to android development,some how I am *able to load googlemap in android using MapView* ,

Now I want to **find distance between two geopoints** .

For that I found that it can be done

> using json  API (Directions Service )

but *not able to get url from Api* ,which is the best approach to draw path between two places?( including the time distance between places).....

I am following this link as reference http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/  but its not working for me ...

Comment: ... **Time** distance? At **which speed**?

Comment: by driving speed in vehcile   @Der Golem

Comment: So, at 0 Km/h? at 2000 Mph? `Statistical Expected Travel Duration in hrs = Distance / Speed`

Answer (score 0):

First, you can find straight distance using:

```
Location loc1 = new Location();
loc1.setLatitude(43.44556);
loc1.setLongitude(88.56567);
Location loc2 = new Location();
loc2.setLatitude(45.44556);
loc2.setLongitude(83.56567);

double distance = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);
```

Second, in order to find the time it takes, I would suggest using [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/). Super easy to use and free

EDIT: Additional details for google places api (which will indeed give you a poly line which you can easily overlay onto your map)

```
static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api";
/**
 * Given a destination place, this will calculate the disance and time it will take to get there from your current location
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/
 * @param place destination place
 * @return String array with index 0 the distance text, index 1 the duration text, and index 2 being the ETA
 */
private String[] getRouteDet(LatLng place, double currentLat, double currentLon) {
    final String APPENDAGES = "/directions";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + APPENDAGES + OUT_JSON);
    sb.append("?key=");
    sb.append(getResources().getString(R.string.google_places_key));
    try {
        sb.append("&origin=");
        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(Double.toString(currentLat),"utf8"));
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(Double.toString(currentLon,"utf8"));
        sb.append("&destination=");
        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(Double.toString(place.latitude),"utf8"));
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(Double.toString(place.longitude), "utf8"));
        sb.append("&departure_time=now");
        sb.append("&mode=");
        sb.append("driving");
        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        if (jsonObj.getString("status").equals("ZERO_RESULTS")) return null;
        JSONObject result = jsonObj.getJSONArray("routes").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs")
                .getJSONObject(0);
        String distance = result.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text");
        String duration = result.getJSONObject("duration").getString("text");
        long durationVal = result.getJSONObject("duration").getLong("value");
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.US);
        return new String[]{distance, duration, formatter.format(System.currentTimeMillis()+durationVal*1000)};
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Polyline code:

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(15).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true);
//Loop through all of your LatLng steps and add each to the polyline:
//    options.add(step);
map.addPolyline(options);
```

Comment: I am having difficulty in drawing path @mray

Comment: Updated my answer to include the google places API code which you can obtain all of the steps in the route, then can iterate through all of those LatLng coordinates to generate the Polyline which I also gave the code for that

Comment: thank you @mray I will let you know If my problem is solved ..it means a lot